# Is there any way to access my nodejs console on linux server?

Tags: linux, node.js, terminal, console

I tried https://npmjs.org/package/node-monkey and it is working fine , but I wonder if there any way to access it using ssh ?

Thanks

Comment: Set up a SSH tunnel and use it from a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

No. I do not think that is possible. It uses a web browser. You might be able to use it with the venerable `lynx` (but I do not think you would enjoy it if you tried it).